# nginx not sending php page source

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to install OwnCloud on my already existing nginx webserver with the web installer but it doesn't send the page

The Source received by the browser: [source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bddb9.png)

When it loads it doesn't display anything

Comment: Blank screens on PHP scripts almost *always* mean a useful error is sitting in your webserver's log files.

Comment: Check the `/var/log/nginx.error.log` log for hints or possibly there will be something like a `/var/log/php-fpm.log`.  
  
If there is nothing there, please post your nginx configuration and php-fpm copnfiguration